# AWS credentials already present after sudo installing awscli on RPi OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, aws-cli

When I install awscli on an RPi OS with `sudo apt install awscli`, after installation if I run the command `sudo aws configure`, I get the following output.[image]

This seems odd to me because why are there credentials already present for the sudo user when I've just installed the awscli?
If I run just `aws configure`, there are no credentials already stored.

Comment: Could be some old credentials that you had there previously.

Comment: The credentials would be in ~/.aws perhaps.